# Best way to dynamically change the page content?

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically change the page content without reloading it.
Also I would like to change the url, meta tags, etc.

What should I use to achieve such result?

Comment: Use angular js routing

Comment: use spfjs, it can do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pjax. From it's [github page](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) it says.

> pjax is a jQuery plugin that uses ajax and pushState to deliver a fast
>   browsing experience with real permalinks, page titles, and a working
>   back button.
>
> pjax works by grabbing html from your server via ajax and replacing
>   the content of a container on your page with the ajax'd html. It then
>   updates the browser's current URL using pushState without reloading
>   your page's layout or any resources (JS, CSS), giving the appearance
>   of a fast, full page load. But really it's just ajax and pushState.

Consider this eaxmple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- styles, scripts, etc -->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
    Go to <a href="/page/2">next page</a>.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Your script.

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')
```

When a click occur on `a` it will attr the `href` and send a ajax request to that link and whole `pjax-container` will replace with new content's `pjax-container`. Same for the form sublit.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
    $.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-container')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS is a framework which will dominate your code architecture. It is however one way to solve your problem with routing: You have several states and every state contains an HTML template. If you switch to another state, the page content will change. If you are an experienced JavaScript developer, you might want to learn and dive into the world of AngularJS, but make sure, you want to take the rather steep learning curve.

If your sole purpose is to switch the content of your page, you can also use jQuery for that. Just select an element on your page and remove its content. Then, add another HTML template to the element. Here is some sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pageElement').empty().html('<h2>Title</h2><p>This is some content.</p>');
});
```

You can also use the jQuery `.load()` function to inject an existing HTML template file to an element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pageElement').empty().load('/template.html');
});
```

Comment: In addition to @ssc-hrep3 - you should probably add a "loading" bar instead of making the element "empty". Sometimes ajax requests don't respond with status 200 (i.e. timed out connection, error 500, etc) or are simply taking a bit longer than usual and the user starts wondering what's going on. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  do this $stateProvider. In **routes.js** set state

```
.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  '$httpProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
 function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider,  $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');   
        $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            data: { isPublic: true },
            templateUrl: 'templates/AdminUser/login.html',
            controller: 'AdminUserController'
        });
    }]);
```

and in **controller** when u redirect to login then use this like

```
$state.transitionTo('login');
```

this is short example, you can use multipal state like this way. and redirect to url **without reload.**